# c# Fluent SQL Helper - Syntax improvement

Tags: c#, linq, syntax

I'm writing a little library to help building SQL requests (only doing SELECTs for the moment) but I'm not satisfied with an aspect of the syntax, here's an exemple to explain:

```
var db = FluentDb.WithConnectionString("SqlCeTest");

var query = db.From("Customers")
              .Where(FS.Col("Age") > 18 & FS.Col("Name").StartsWith("L"))
              .OrderBy("BirthDate")
              .Select("Name", "Age", "BirthDate");

var customers = query.ToList((r) => new
                             {
                                 Name = r.Get<string>("Name"),
                                 Age = r.Get<int>("Age"),
                                 BirthDate = r.Get<DateTime?>("BirtDate")
                             });
```

The part I'd like to improve is the `FS.Col("ColumnName")`, it's supposed to stand for FluentSql.Column (return a new FluentColumn(columnName)), but I find it a bit long in that context, what I'd really like is to be able to use just `Col("ColumnName")`...

Do anybody see a trick I could use to achieve that, or another syntax idea?

My ideas:

- Extension method on string: `Where("Name".Col() == "Jon")`
- Lambda expression with factory object using indexer: `.Where(c => c["Name"] == "Jon")`

Anyone see something better/shorter/nicer?

**Edit:**

my second idea looks good but there's a downside if i use it in another context:
I sometime need to use FluentColumns in Select (or OrderBy, or GroupBy) statements like that:

```
query.Select(FS.Col("Name").As("Customer"), FS.Col("OrderId").Count().As("OrdersCount"));
```

I would have to repeat the 'c => ' for each column...

Comment: Your second approach is very natural and will make the users of your library understand what it is doing without much of "figuring-out-the-magic".

Comment: actually I had the idea when writing the question, I'll probably implement it, but it couldn't hurt to ask for better solutions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for information, I decided to go with an indexer syntax on the FluentDb instance:

`db["Customer", "AddressId"]` mean column AddressId of table Customer,

an alternative syntax is available: `db["Customer"]["AddressId"]`

So in the end, it's gonna be (I still need to find a trick to make the Column declaration without table nice):

```
.Where(db["Customer", "Name"] == "Jon")
```

Answer (score 0):

A twist on your second option (which is pretty good) would be to use a dynamic expandoobject in the lambda instead of a string indexer.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2009/10/01/dynamic-in-c-4-0-introducing-the-expandoobject.aspx

Comment: It's a good idea, but I'd like to stay away from dynamic to be able to parametrize the column names (but an another lib make an awesome  usage of dynamic for DB access already: Simple.Data)